# Analog Input from Arduino to Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, arduino

I am coding an application in Android Studio that uses analog inputs from an arduino. I am trying to send analog input from an Arduino Pro mini to an Android App. However, I cannot connect straight to the phone (USB port isn't available). The method I've thought of is to connect both the phone and Arduino to PC and read the Analog input using Android Studio and Use my phone to run the application instead of an emulator. Would this work in real time.

Is it possible to have the Android Studio run the app and the app still reads information from the Arduino real time? The application reacts to analog inputs from the Arduino. So I need to find a way to access the arduino in android studio and run the app through android studio in place of its emulator

I can't find any sources so if anyone has a clue please help me. Thank You!

Comment: can post some code ?

Answer (score 1):

You should post this to the Arduino StackExchange forum: http://arduino.stackexchange.com.

A couple things:

Android Studio is just for developing Android apps, it's not going to help you read data from the Arduino.  You would need to write a separate app for the PC that would moderate between the Android and Arduino.  Not fun.

When you say "USB port isn't available" I assume you mean the *host* port.  Actually, many newer Android devices are able to be a USB host, so you would just need the right dongle to be able to connect the two.  Then you would use the classes in package `android.hardware.usb` like `UsbManager` to connect to the Arduino.

Another thing you might think about is getting a BlueTooth shield for your Arduino and connecting to the Android with BlueTooth.

Hey! Wanna be a real Evil Genius(TM)? Write some code to flash the LED on the Arduino like Morse Code or Navy signaling, then write some Android code to read the video from the camera and turn the LED flashes back into data! Impress your friends! Put it on your resume!

Just some random ideas to get you going.  I think the folks on the Arduino StackExchange forum can be more help.

Comment: Thank You! I'll try the Arduino StackExchange!